# How to get completed/remaining value from work item using web hooks in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to create web hook at work items updating event in azure devops server. Is there a possibility to get old and new value of fields 'Completed work' and 'Remaining work' from the http request? Or any workarounds? I want to write tool to observe time that was spent for tasks.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a web hook on the **Work item updated event** in azure devops. The old and new value of fields 'Completed work' and 'Remaining work' are automatically included in the Http request body.

So you can get the old and new value of updated fields in your web hook server directly.

See below output from my test web hook server `console.log(req.body.resource.fields);`

[image]

Check the Sample payload of the request body on Work item updated event [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#work-item-updated).

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe it works only for tasks, but not for bugs? I tried test request (azure devops uses mock bug for sending test request) and there was no information about  'Completed work' and 'Remaining work'. And there is no information about it in the sample payload at the site (it uses bug for example). I think that the thing is that they use settings fro bugs as backlog, but not development item.